# Django, how pass variable to flatpage?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a few flatpages in my app menu, so, my question is, how I'll pass variables to my flatpages if i don't have any view for flatpages?

here is my urls.py:

```
(r'',include('django.contrib.flatpages.urls')),
```

I dont have any view's for any flatpages, so I dont know how I'll pass variable to my flatpages, like news, etc for display news column...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two possibilities I can think of:

1. Write a [Template Context Processor](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors), which adds the latest news objects to the context. I found [James Bennett's tutorial](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/14/django-tips-template-context-processors/) helpful.
2. Write a [custom template tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/). James Bennett has a [tutorial on this](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/07/django-tips-write-better-template-tags/) as well. I haven't followed it, so I can't guarantee it works with Django 1.x.

As an aside, when using flatpages, if you add

```
'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware'
```

to your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in settings.py, then you can remove the flatpages item from urls.py.

Comment: This tutorial from James Bennett is the best :D, pow solution, thanks

Comment: Which tutorial did you use? Context Processor or Template Tag?

Comment: Hi Alasdir... Template Tag :)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/14/django-tips-template-context-processors/

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/?from=olddocs#template-context-processors